# Air for Android - How to receive content from other apps?

Tags: android, air

I'm building an Android app with Adobe Air 3.6 and Flash CS 6.
Is it possible to [receive content from other apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html), e.g. a link from the browser?

I couldn't find a working example anywhere yet.

Comment: What you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the intents you need in the proper section of your app descriptor. Look for the android-related section:

```
...
<android>
        <manifestAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
                <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
                <application android:enabled="true">
                    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>

                                    <!-- ADD INTENTS HERE -->

                    </activity>
                </application>
            </manifest>
        ]]>
        </manifestAdditions>
        <!-- Color depth for the app (either "32bit" or "16bit"). Optional. Default 16bit before namespace 3.0, 32bit after -->
        <!-- <colorDepth></colorDepth> -->
</android>
...
```

Please note this is only half of the story. In order to properly consume those intents you should handle them in your code, something like this:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE,onInvoke);
...
function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void
{
  /* handle your intent here */
}
```

Please refer to official docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html).